# WPF .NET Framework 4 Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog skipping and not showing dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

Using following code to save a file in WPF

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Program skips save dialog, to see what happens, When debugging I get  `Nullable<bool> result` false.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess the context here is hidden. What you posted is simply correct and should work but the context around is what we need. Is there any threading involved here? Have you looked at the Output window to see if there is any exception thrown silently and possibly that will cause some strange debugging result...

Comment: Agree that the code on itself is perfectly fine. Searching similar post in stackoverflow. Might have many different cause for this problem. First thing first, the SaveDialog. ShowDialog should work if u put the code to a blank project for testing?

Comment: Ok, I have tried isolated code, and works correctly, Then the program in other x64 computer and works having , I am going to do more tests, however what would be the best way to track the issue?